# If $\hat \alpha \sim N(\alpha,\sigma)$, is $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[\phi(\alpha X)]$ where $\phi$ is the Gaussian function?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

Let $\hat \alpha \sim N(\alpha,\sigma)$.

Obviously
$$
E[\hat \alpha - \alpha] = E[\hat \alpha] - E[\alpha] = \alpha - \alpha = 0.
$$

Now define $\phi$ to be the Gaussian function
$$
\phi(x) = e^{-x^2/2}.
$$

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable. Is it possible to use the properties of $\hat \alpha$ and/or the Gaussian function to show that $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[\phi(\alpha X)]$? Or does this equality not hold?

**Attempt 1:** whuber suggestion

\begin{align}
E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] & = E[E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)|X]] \\
& \le E[\phi(E[\hat \alpha X|X])] \\
& = E[\phi(X E[\hat \alpha|X])] \\
& = E[\phi(\alpha X)].
\end{align}
I assume this is what was suggested by whuber. I have not seen Jensen's inequality in the case of conditional expectation so I just used it as I would for regular expectation. If the above is correct, it gives us a very useful inequality but the question of whether $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[\phi(\alpha X)]$ is still open.

**Attempt 2:** Taylor's/mean-value theorem
We start with
\begin{align}
E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] & = E[E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)|X]]. 
\end{align}

My approach here is based on treating $X$ as a constant in the conditional expectation which then means $\alpha X$ is a constant and $\hat \alpha X$ is a random variable multiplied by a constant. Based on that, I apply Taylor's theorem as stated in the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Proof_in_the_univariate_case). So for the conditional expectation I have

\begin{align}
E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)|X] &= E[\phi(\alpha X) + \phi'(\overline{\alpha X})(\hat \alpha X - \alpha X)|X] \\
&= E[\phi(\alpha X) + \phi'(\overline{\alpha X})(\hat \alpha - \alpha) X|X] \\
&= E[\phi(\alpha X)|X] + E[\phi'(\overline{\alpha X})(\hat \alpha - \alpha) X|X] \\ 
&= E[\phi(\alpha X)|X] + \phi'(\overline{\alpha X}) X E[(\hat \alpha - \alpha) |X] \\
&= E[\phi(\alpha X)|X], \\
\end{align}
since $E[(\hat \alpha - \alpha) |X] = E[\hat \alpha - \alpha] = 0$. We need to take the expectation of this quantity since this was just the inner expectation. When we do this we get
$$
E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)|X]] = E[E[\phi(\alpha X)|X]] = E[\phi(\alpha X)].
$$
So in this approach, it seems $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[\phi(\alpha X)]$, but I'm not sure whether I have made a mistake, particularly in the context of how I used Taylor's theorem in conjunction with conditional expectation?

Comment: Although you state an *equality,* you ask "does this *inequality* not hold."  Which one is the question??  Regardless, the subject matter suggests a review of Jensen's Inequality would serve you well.

Comment: Ok I looked at Jensen's inequality, and since $\phi$ is concave, we have $$E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] \le \phi(E[\hat \alpha X]) = \phi(\alpha E[X]),$$
and
$$E[\phi(\alpha X)] \le \phi(E[\alpha X]) = \phi(\alpha E[X]).$$  But this just gives the same bound for both expectations, it doesn't tell us whether $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)] = E[\phi(\alpha X)]$?

Comment: Condition the expectation on $X,$ apply Jensen, and then take the expectation over $X.$

Comment: Ok great thanks whuber, I will give that a try now. I also tried something else just now involving Taylors' theorem and it seemed to show the expression is true. I will edit my post to show both methods once I have tried your suggest.

Comment: @whuber I have edited my post to show both approaches. Approach 2 seems to suggest that the equality holds, but I'm not sure if what I have done is truly valid. Approach 1 seems to lead to an inequality but does not resolve whether the equality holds.

Comment: Taylor's theorem is essentially useless for establishing an inequality unless you pay strict attention to the magnitude of the remainder term.

Comment: Yes but the remainder term vanishes in this case because $E[\hat \alpha - \alpha | X] = 0$ so there is no need to account for it.

Comment: But it seems something is wrong with the Taylor approach in any case as it doesn't work if $\phi(x) = x^2$ for example. I'm not sure why yet. What about the Jensen inequality approach, that seems to lead to an inequality between $E[\phi(\hat \alpha X)]$ and $E[\phi(\alpha X)]$ but doesn't say whether they are equal or not.

Comment: Check the conditions under which equality holds in Jensen's inequality, then conclude the inequality is strict in your case.

Comment: Ok so Jensen's inequality says we have a strict inequality if $\phi$ is strictly concave. But actually $\phi$ isnt concave at all since it is a Gaussian function..it is only log concave. So it seems Jensen's equality is not valid here.

Comment: Ah, true -- I had not noticed that.  This means you should be able to find counterexamples. Since you aren't assuming $X$ is independent of $\hat\alpha,$ construct $X$ as a suitable function of $\hat\alpha.$

Comment: No problem, at least it let me get some practise with Jensen's inequality ;-)